# Is "lingua Latina studenda pergit" grammatical?

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, gerundive

I want to say "people continue to study Latin", and I came up with *lingua Latina studenda pergit*.
Is such a combination gerundive and *pergere* grammatical?
It must be understandable, but I do not recall ever seeing it used or discussed.
Another option would be *lingua Latina studeri pergit*, but I want to know if the gerundive works, too.

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but I don't think I've ever seen a gerundive construction (as distinct from a future passive participle) used in the nominative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. First, are you sure that *pergit* can be used in this sense? I would use *pergo* to indicate a sense of progression, and I would have an agent in mind as its subject, someone who continues to move in a certain direction. Perhaps *permanet* or *perstat* would fit?

As to the gerundive construction, i.e. a gerundive that is used dominantly, I believe it cannot be used in the nominative, nor in the accusative without a preposition. The same applies a to gerunds, mutatis mutandis. In its non-dominant use, a gerundive has a sense of obligation or prediction, which, as you say, is not what we want in this example: "the Latin language continues to be compulsory to be studied"; or as an ablative: "it continues while studying the Latin language".

But the passivity of the gerund is also problematic here, because *studeo* is normally intransitive: it goes with the dative and cannot normally be passivised with a subject. A gerundive is also passive, but *studendus* and *linga Latina* could not agree in case. Then what would the gerundive agree with?

In the nominative, one would use a simple noun or an infinitive rather than a gerundive, to express "doing something" as a subject or direct object. In this case, a noun comes first to mind:

> Studium lingae Latinae permanet.

An infinitive is possible in theory:

> ? Studere linguae Latinae permanet.

Somehow, I don't like this very much, but it's hard to explain why not. Perhaps verbs that mean "continue" are not often used with infinitive constructions? At least I don't think *permanet* is constructed with an infinitive; and *perstat* with an infinitive means something else, as does *pergit*.

> Linguae Latinae adhuc studemus / semper studebimus.

This has a slightly different meaning, but it could be appropriate.

Comment: I think the problem with *?Studere linguae Latinae permanet* is that infinitive subjects rarely take any verb other than *esse* and its compounds.

Comment: @TKR: Hmm you may be right; I can't think of any counter-examples. But how about as a subject complement?: *? lingua Latina permanet legi*. I don't think that works either. That construction only works with copulae, I suppose, and *permaneo* isn't a proper copula.

Comment: I think you're right -- that doesn't sound correct to me either. The issue there seems to be that *permaneo* doesn't take an infinitive complement, active or passive.

Comment: @TKR: Yes, I think so too. And, while some other verbs do take an infinitive as a complement, like *persto*, it won't be in the proper thematic role.

Comment: Thanks! I mistook *studere* for a transitive verb. It's good to have this misconception corrected, but the main question is about using gerundive with *pergere*. I have seen *pergere* with infinitive to mean "to continue to do something", and my dictionary also gives this use. You have convinced me that I shouldn't use gerundive even if I change to a transitive verb.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand this later (I'm on my phone), but I'd offer *Etiamnunc linguae Latinae studetur.* ("People are still studying Latin," or, more literally, "Study is still given to Latin.")

Comment: I would like that, but I've tried to find passive finite forms of *studeo* in the HP corpus, and there are hardly any.  *Studetur* gives one result, from Iustianiaus, and *studentur* zero results. The word doesn't seem to be used in the passive in the classical age? Still, I think you can make a case for it, as a late form.

Comment: @Cerberus Yeah, my position on such matters seems to be in a state of constant flux, but at the moment I don't find a lack of attestation in such a case persuasive as a guide to modern usage.